# Gap above fixed header on Android 4+ browser

Tags: android, css, browser

Any ideas how to remove the gap (on the screen) whitch appears during scrolling?
Header has position fixed and the gap appears only on Androd (tested on Android 4.0.4).

[image: Gap]

Part of the code responsible for the header:

**HTML:**

> ```
> <div data-role="page" id="settings">
>     <div class="holo-action-bar">
>         <h1><span>Settings</span></h1>
>     </div>
>     <div class="content content-inner"></div>
> </div>
> ```

**CSS:**

> ```
> .holo-action-bar {
>   background-color: #333;
>   color: #fff;
>   display: block;
>   position: fixed;
>   top: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
>   width: 100%;
>   z-index: 1000;
> }
> ```

Also you can see example at [jquery mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html)

**UPDATE:**

The problem doesn't occur on iOS (tested on iOS 5+)

Comment: Post some code we dont any chance to find out what you did to make it look like this.. make a www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: @SimonPertersen code added

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution :

this is CSS problem on phonegap.

```
body {
   << height : 100%; don't use it >>
   width: 100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   top: -1px;
}
```

HardwareAccelaration : true

Answer (score 0):

But delete your data-position="fixed"

make a class

```
<div id="header"><h1>Fixed header!</h1></div>
```

css:

```
#header{
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
}
```

**EDIT** *

Have you tried to check the margin on your inner object? 
if its a p tag or h1 or so they have standard margin

if i check out the link you gave btw i dont like jquery mobile cause it gives more problems than it helps tbh.. but anyhow
it seems that it have a border on 1px or so do you have a link to your site?

Comment: I don't use jQuery Mobile (I agree with your sentence about jQM). I wanted to show with an example that the same problem is also there.

Comment: atleast do top:-1px; as a hack if you dont send code i cant debug it so if you make a jsfiddle i would be glad to debug it for you

Comment: top: -1px; also leaves a gap on my mobile. Even top: -10px;

Comment: It's a common issue that cannot be fixed like this, the hack I am using (only for Android browser) is to set position to absolute then when I detect page scroll I update the top value of the #header.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it accidentally when I added this line in my activity.java:

```
mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

and `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in the manifest under the `<application>` tag. This tries to disable the software renderer in favor of the hardware one, and it worked on my 4.0.1 device.

If you are using webview with the fixed header and footer, you also might want to add the following too so the flashing animation over the header/footer disappears:

```
mWebView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the 1px gap above the fixed header in an Android 4 pad, when using Intel App Framework 2 with Cordova 3.0.0. With the target Android version set to 4.3.

The problem was not there when I set the target Android version to 2.3.3 in previous projects.

At the end I found that when I set hardwareAccelerated="false" (in two places) in AndroidManifest.xml, the 1 px gap is gone.